# What does it mean for a node to have a negative height in a binary tree?

Tags: java, binary-tree, treenode

I am looking at this code which defines the `height` function, which returns the height of the given `TreeNode` in a binary tree. I don't understand why it should return a value of -1? What does it mean for the height to be *negative*?

```
int height(TreeNode root) {
    // ...
    int left = height(root.left);
    int right = height(root.right); 
    if(left == -1 || right == -1) return -1;
}
```

Comment: That's presumably the `height` of the tree, not the "int value". And a `height` of `-1` implies it contains nothing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in your original question you wrote:

> when a TreeNode's int value is -1

We don't see a Node's *value* here, but its *height*. The `height` function returns the height of the node that is given as argument to it, not its value. This is now corrected in the question.

The height of a node is defined as the length of the longest path from that node to any of the leaves in the tree it is the root of. So for instance, take this tree:

```
       17
      /  \
     5    31
      \
       8
```

The node with value 17 has a height of 2 because the longest path to a leaf is 2, (having edge 17-5 and edge 5-8).

The node with value 5 has a height of 1, and the nodes 31 and 8 each have a height of 0.

But what happens when you call `height` with an argument that is `null`? That is when the function should return -1. It is like saying *"you went down one edge too far -- you followed an edge that is not there"*.

Now back to your code:

When `left` is -1, it means that `root.left` is `null`. The logical expression `left == -1` is equivalent to `root.left == null`. A similar equivalence holds for `right` and `root.right`.

The *logic* of this `height` function is *wrong*. It should never return -1 when `root` is a valid node. As explained above, it should *only* return -1 when the given node (`root`) is `null` itself, but here we see code that returns -1 when `root` is a leaf node (i.e. both `root.left` and `root.right` are `null`). But in that case  it should return 0, not -1.

A correct `height` function could look like this:

```
int height(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) return -1; // This is the only case where we return -1
    // The root's height is determined by the height of its children
    int left = height(root.left);
    int right = height(root.right); 
    // ...the child with the greatest height is determining it:
    // we add one level to that height, which represents the root itself:
    return 1 + Math.max(left, right); 
}
```